# I have created a FileUploader class in PHP which validates and uploads any submited file. works fine but does not move the uploaded file

Tags: php

I am working on a project and so I am writing Object Oriented PHP. Hence, I have created a class called FileUploader. This class has all the method to validate file size, and file extension type as well as create directories if not existing.
Everything works just fine but I noticed that it only creates empty directories and does not move the uploaded files. I tried accessing the File error form the stored property but it always gives 0 as the error code

This is the FileUploader class

```
<?php
namespace Utility\Classes;
    class FileUploader
{
    //property declarations
    protected $error_msg = array();
    protected $tmp_file_name;
    protected $max_file_size;
    protected $target_location;
    protected $allowed_file_type = array();
    protected $File;
    protected $default_file_name = true;

    private $backlink_step;
    private $unit_size; //to keep track of measurement unit of upload sizes MB|KB|BYTES


    function __construct(array $file, array $allowed_ext = [], int $file_max_size = 5)
    {

        $this->File = $file;
        $this->backlink_step = '';
        $this->set_allowed_extensions($allowed_ext);
        $this->set_max_upload_size($file_max_size);
    }



    /*This method helps to make sure that files are uploaded to the exact location as desired
    *as in the case of deep nesting of subdirectory process
    */
    function set_backlink_step($prfx)
    {
        $this->backlink_step = $prfx;
    }

    function  set_target(string $target, $dated = false)
    {
        $this->target_location = $target;
        if ($dated) {
            $this->target_location .=  "/" . $date = date("M-Y");
        }
    }

    function get_target()
    {
        return $this->target_location;
    }
    //method to set valid/allowed file types
    function set_allowed_extensions(array $allowed_ext)
    {
        $this->allowed_file_type = $allowed_ext;
    }
    //method to get the allowed file extensions
    function get_allowed_extensions()
    {
        return $this->allowed_file_type;
    }

    function set_error_msg($err)
    {
        $this->error_msg[] = $err;
    }

    function get_error_msg()
    {
        return $this->error_msg;
    }

    function set_file_name($name)
    {
        $this->File['name'] = $name;
    }

    function get_file_name()
    {
        return $this->File['name'];
    }

    function get_tmp_name()
    {
        return $this->File['tmp_name'];
    }

    /**
     * @description: method to return file size in a specified unit
     * @param:String ['TB'|'MB'|'KB'|'B'] default MB
     * @return: Int file size 
     *  */
    function get_file_size(String $unit = "MB")
    {

        if (strtolower($unit) === "tb") {
            $quadrant = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
        } elseif (strtolower($unit) === "mb") {
            $quadrant = 1024 * 1024;
        } elseif (strtolower($unit) === "kb") {
            $quadrant = 1024;
        } elseif (strtolower($unit) === "b") {
            $quadrant = 1;
        }
        $size = $this->file_size() / $quadrant;
        return number_format($size, 2);
    }

    /**
     * @return int size of the file 
     * */
    function file_size()
    {
        $fsize = $this->File['size'];
        return $fsize;
    }

    /* Method to get the extension name of a file eg: jpg,mp4 */
    function get_ext()
    {
        $extension = explode('.', $this->get_file_name());
        return "." . end($extension);
    }



    function validate($allowed_ext = [])
    {


        //fall back to the object allowed_file_type property if param not set by user
        if (empty($allowed_ext)) {
            $allowed_ext = $this->get_allowed_extensions();
        }

        //validate allowed file type if specified in the array
        if (!empty($allowed_ext)) {
            if (!$this->is_allowed_extension($allowed_ext)) {
                $this->set_error_msg("Type of '{$this->get_file_name()} does not match allowed file types [" . implode('|', $this->get_allowed_extensions()) . "]");
                return false;
            }
        }

        //validate file size
        if ($this->is_above_max_upload_size()) {
            $this->set_error_msg("Size of the file '{$this->get_file_name()}' is larger than max allowed size of {$this->get_max_upload_size()}");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /*Method to upload file 
    * @return: the uploaded target location
    */
    function upload_file()
    {
        //create necessary directories if not in existence
        $this->create_dir();
        $target = $this->backlink_step . $this->target_location .  "/" . $this->get_file_name();
        //attempt upload of the file
        if (move_uploaded_file($this->tmp_file_name,  $target)) {
            //update target location with the filename
            return $target;
        } else {
            //return false;
            die("tmp_name: {$this->get_tmp_name()} \n target: {$target} \n Error: {$this->File['error']}");
        }
    }



    /*This method sets the maximum upload size for file track and album_art respectively
    *This method ignores invalid value for unit and replaces it with bytes*/
    function set_max_upload_size($file_size, $unit = "MB")
    {
        $mulitplicant = 1;
        if (strtolower($unit) === "tb") {
            $multiplicant = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
        } elseif (strtolower($unit) === "mb") {
            $multiplicant = 1024 * 1024;
        } elseif (strtolower($unit) === "kb") {
            $multiplicant = 1024;
        } else {
            $unit = "Bytes";
        }

        $this->max_file_size = $multiplicant * $file_size; //set max size for file
        $this->unit_size = strtoupper($unit);
    }

    function get_max_upload_size()
    {
        return $this->max_file_size;
    }

    /*Method to compare the size of files to be uploaded with the maximum allowed size*/
    function is_above_max_upload_size()
    {
        $file_unit = $this->unit_size;
        //return FALSE if upload size > max size otherwise TRUE
        return ($this->file_size() > $this->get_max_upload_size()) ? true : false;
    }

    /*Method to check if upload file is allowed in by extension name
    *The first paramater takes the string of the actual file extension
    *The second parameter takes an array of allowed extensions
    */
    function is_allowed_extension(array $allowed_ext)
    {
        return (!in_array($this->get_ext(), $allowed_ext)) ? false : true;
    }


//method to create directories
    function create_dir()
    {
        //check if user set a storage location and attempt to create the location
        if (empty($this->get_target())) {
            $this->set_error_msg('Target Not set.');
            return false;
        }
        //Create the directory
        $location = explode('/', $this->get_target());
        $prepend = $this->backlink_step . "";
        foreach ($location as $key => $value) {
            if (!is_dir($prepend . $value)) {
                mkdir($prepend . $value);
            }
            $prepend .= $value . "/";
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have another php script where I process the uploaded file by instantiating the FileUploader Class with the $_FILES variable process.php

```
  require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";
  
  use Utility\Classes\FileUploader;
  //Instantiate new FileUploader with the files to be uploaded.
          $LogoUploader = new FileUploader($_FILES['logo'], ['.png', '.jpg']);
//validate logo size and type - Upload to folder if everything Ok
          $logo_validated = $LogoUploader->validate();
//upload files that passed validation
          if ($logo_validated) {
              $LogoUploader->set_target($location);
              $LogoUploader->set_backlink_step('../');
              $ltarget = $LogoUploader->upload_file();

              if (!$ltarget) {
                  //upload error
                  print_error($LogoUploader->get_error_msg());
                  exit;
              } else { //upload success
                  print "Logo uploaded successfully";
              }
          } else { //validation error
              print_error($LogoUploader->get_error_msg());
              exit;
          }
```

Please what am I not doing right?? everything is ok, validation is working, user can set the upload target and if it does not exist, it will be created but it does not upload the file into the created directory or anywhere else in my working directory

Comment: I can't see where you define `$location`. Have you forgotten to copy it into the example or is it unset?

Comment: so far as I can tell you do not assign a value to `$this->tmp_file_name` so the `upload_file` baulks at the `move_uploaded_file` stage

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to copy that line where I declared `$location`. I actually declared it somewhere above after the line where I imported the class. I mistakenly omitted it along with some comments I have above while copying the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change the following line

```
 if (move_uploaded_file($this->tmp_file_name,  $target)) {
```

to

```
if (move_uploaded_file( $this->get_tmp_name(),  $target )) {
```

in the `upload_file` method. ie:

```
public function upload_file(){
    $this->create_dir();
    $target = $this->backlink_step . $this->target_location .  "/" . $this->get_file_name();
    
    if (move_uploaded_file( $this->get_tmp_name(),  $target )) {
        return $target;
    } else {
        die("tmp_name: {$this->get_tmp_name()} \n target: {$target} \n Error: {$this->File['error']}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Prof, I really can't believe that this was my problem which has given me some had time so far... But It indeed solved my problem. Thanks a lot for this wonderful observation

Comment: I just discovered that the property `tmp_file_name` was never assigned any value in the `FileUploader` class